# Getting map to return all T/F values for list matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Using the syntax below:

```
from operator import eq
a = ['a','b', 'c']
b = ['a', 'b']
list(map(eq, a, b))
```

I'm getting:

```
# [True, True]
```

How to get `T/F` result for the missing `'c'` element:

```
# [True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `starmap` and `zip_longest` from `itertools` with None as the `fillvalue` in `zip_longest` to fill the missing value position:

```
In [34]: from itertools import zip_longest, starmap

In [35]: list(starmap(eq, zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=None)))
Out[35]: [True, True, False]
```

Comment: Careful though: If the last element in `a` is the same as the fillvalue, you'll get `[True, True, True]` as the result.

Comment: For that I would suggest using a new object: `fillvalue=object()`. With that it will never be equal to any existing object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version without using `itertools`:

```
def tmp_func(a,b):
    i = 0
    m = len(max(a,b))
    len_diff = len(a) - len(b)

    if(len_diff < 0):
       a.extend(abs(len_diff)*[''])
    elif (len_diff > 0):
       b.extend(abs(len_diff)*[''])

    while i < m:
        yield (a[i], b[i])
        i=i+1

a = ['a','b', 'c']
b = ['a', 'b']

list(map(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], tmp_func(a,b)))
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False]
```